Upload Android APK file to Firebase Storage
I have one use case where I need to upload the APK file to Firebase Storage.
Stuck here for a long time, not sure why it's not working and how to make it work.
But when I trying to upload a file from web application call the API, I'm receiving 400 BAD request
POST https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/-----.appspot.com/o?name=applications%2F-O0ZzNWYNzsqOk8j9ktD%2Fversions%2F-O0_7tl6u72kaAmm3xTK.apk&upload_id=ACJd0NrwhTZC7vpY5ORvSSkMaJ9cZFGw0-e1zZZ5WmdPBvuLbBNQZF0v1IXegzqh7qTkVIiepRPq7f-ixfgt9LU_EehFTHJWNMmgnU5wftAtdqSB3g&upload_protocol=resumable 400 (Bad Request)

connection.ts:81

FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)


code: 400
message: "Executable files are forbidden on the Spark billing plan."

Expected behaviour is -> apk should upload without any issue.

From the Firebase documentation on uploading files:

Note: For Spark plan projects, Firebase blocks upload and hosting of certain executable file types for Windows (files with .exe, .dll and .bat extensions), Android (.apk extension) and Apple (.ipa extension) by Cloud Storage for Firebase and Firebase Hosting. This policy exists to prevent abuse on our platform. Projects on the Blaze plan are not affected. For more information, see this FAQ.

The "Spark plan" in this refers to Firebase free-to-use, no-cost plan. So to serve such files from Firebase Storage, you will have to upgrade to Firebase's paid plan.

Thanks @frank its working after upgrade the plan..

Good to hear you got it working @RahulRanjan. --- Also see What should I do when someone answers my question?
